# Oneplus One not found in Eclipse device manager

Tags: android, eclipse-adt, cyanogenmod, oneplusone

I found some questions where the Android devices were not found with Android ADT.
I tried another cable, restarting Eclipse and the OnePlus One, installing new drivers, changing the USB port and some other different tips.

My OnePlus One shows "USB Debugging" in the notifications but the device can't be found.

Anyone tips?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problems with my phone, here are the steps I made and worked for me.

1. Control Panel
2. Devices Manager
3. Find your android device (it should be there)
4. Right click on the device -> Properties -> Driver
5. Update Driver
6. Browse my computer for driver software
7. Let me pick from a list o devices
8. Select certificate -> Next -> Close

OR

1. Control Panel
2. Devices Manager
3. Find your android device (it should be there)
4. Right click on the device -> Properties -> Driver
5. Update Driver
6. Browse my computer for driver software
7. Select driver
8. Find Android SDK -> USB DRiver
9. Load your driver from there

Hope this helps,
Cheers

Comment: The OPO can not be found in the device manager

I also reinstalled the google drivers.
In the explorer my OPO is existing.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason Windows could not find the correct drivers. The solution for me was to download and run **[this](http://adbdriver.com/downloads/)** tool that installed the correct drivers, as suggested by [this](http://www.reddit.com/r/oneplus/comments/2e7f5f/adb_drivers_for_windows_7/) Reddit post.

[image: After the driver patch]

After hitting the install button my OnePlus One showed up in Eclipse.

[image: Eclipse device manager]

Answer (score 1):

Edit `android_winusb.inf` located at `<sdk>\extras\google\usb_driver\`.

Add the following lines under the sections `[Google.NTx86]` and `[Google.NTamd64]`:

```
;OnePlus One
%SingleAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_05C6&PID_6765
%CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_05C6&PID_6765&MI_01
```

Then install the driver manually (from device manager).